# How EJB container differentiates one client from another in case of @Stateful

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

I am trying to understand what could be done with **@Stateful** beans, given **@SessionScoped** CDI beans. I created this JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("ping")
public class PingResource {

    @Inject
    private StatelessCounter statelessCounter;

    @Inject
    private StatefulCounter statefulCounter;

    @Inject
    private SingletonCounter singletonCounter;

    private long jaxrsCounter;

    @GET
    @Path("/counter")
    public String incrementAndGetCounter() {
        statelessCounter.incrementCounter();
        statefulCounter.incrementCounter();
        singletonCounter.incrementCounter();
        jaxrsCounter++;

        return statelessCounter.getCounter() + " " + statefulCounter.getCounter() + " " + singletonCounter.getCounter() + " " + jaxrsCounter;
    }
}
```

Just to understand behavior of stateful bean. But, everytime I call `/counter` endpoint, I always get a fresh `statefulCounter`. I just want to know what is the criteria for the EJB container to return same stateful object used before; as it is stateful, there must be a way to get the same old object.

Comment: The server doesn't do that, the client is responsible for maintaining the stateful bean instance and keep communicating through that same instance. So if you keep getting a different instance in your sessionScoped bean then I question if the sessionScoped bean itself is properly maintained. It sounds like a new one is created for each invocation of /counter.

Comment: Actually, I haven't marked my resource `/counter` as `@SessionScoped`. Its `@RequestScoped` only (default scope). I am trying to figure out why (in which case) should I use **@Stateful** EJB to maintain a shopping cart instead of **@SessionScoped** CDI bean.